# How to do this website layout with Flex in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap-5

In my last question I asked how to make a simple layout with flex from Bootstrap for a website. I got a correct solution, but now I need a different layout for another website and I would need help again.
Here is a plan how the layout should look:

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaIZS.png)

I am convinced that I have to do this with flex but I couldn't do it because for the moment I am too inexperienced in flex. Please help.

**Update. This is what I got as solution:**

```
<!-- test.html -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  </head>
  <body class="flex-body">
    <div class="flex-row-1">
      <div class="col-3 blue"></div>
      <div class="col-9 orange"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row-2 grey"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
/* test.css */

.blue
{
    background-color: blue;
}

.orange
{
    background-color: orange;
}

.grey
{
    background-color: grey;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

.row
{
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
}

.flex-body
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-row-1
{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

.flex-row-2
{
    display: flex;
    min-height: 35%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use bootstrap grid system,css flex or just give w-25,w-50,w-70
i recommend using grid system for great responsiblity
which one do you prefer?

Comment: It would be very nice if you could post both solutions. Otherwise I would prefer flex. But to mention it, the most important thing is that the height of both rows covers 100% of the browser window :)